# Getting id from HTML with jQuery giving unexpected results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to preface this with the fact that I cannot emphasize how new I am to jQuery, so this is going to be a very simple question.

I am trying to get a little familiar with jQuery and am making a toy application that just replaces some HTML on `mouseover` and `mouseleave`.

I have the following code that I borrowed from w3schools.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
#header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}
#nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;          
}
#section {
    width:350px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;        
}
#footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
   padding:5px;      
}
</style>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
<h1>City Gallery</h1>
</div>

<div id="nav">
<a href="#" class='link' id="london-btn">London</a><br>
<a href="#" class='link' id="paris-btn">Paris</a><br>
<a href="#" class='link' id="tokyo-btn">Tokyo</a><br>
</div>

<div id="section">
<h2>London</h2>
<p>
London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
</p>
<p>
Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia,
its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.
</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
Copyright © W3Schools.com
</div>

<script>
$link = $(".link")

var original = $("#header").html();

$(".link").mouseover(function(){
 $("#header").html("<h1>I mousedover on "+ $link.attr("id") + "</h1>");
});


$(".link").mouseleave(function(){
 $("#header").html(original);
});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am using jquery 2.1.3. I expect to see "I mousedover london-btn" when my mouse hovers over `london-btn`, "I mousedover paris-btn" when my mouse hovers over `paris-btn`, and "I moused over tokyo-btn" when my mouse hovers over `tokyo-btn`, and "City Gallery" any other time.

It almost works, but when I hover over any button, it always says "I mousedover london-btn".

This is just a small exercise in DRY development and jQuery. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
erip

Comment: Change you code to following: '$("#header").html("<h1>I mousedover on "+ $(this).attr("id") + "</h1>");'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than retrieving the `id` of the first `.link` element within the `mouseover` event listener, you need to get the `id` of the element you are mousing over.

Within the event listener, `this` refers to the element that is currently being moused over, therefore you would access the `id` using  `$(this).attr("id")` or `this.id`:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/b7m5L332/)

```
$(".link").on('mouseover', function () {
    $("#header").html("<h1>I mousedover on " + this.id + "</h1>");
});
```

It's worth pointing out that `$(".link")` returns a collection (a jQuery object) of elements. When accessing the `id` using `$(".link").attr("id")`, you are accessing the `id` of the *first* element within the jQuery object. That's why you text would always say 'london'.